# How does JPA find the concrete implementation to call?

Tags: java, jpa, interface

I am working on a project where I've to abstract out the interfaces and separate it with the concrete implementation. For example, JPA is just the interface and under the hood, it calls one of the concrete implementations, for example, Hibernate library. So my question is how does it know which implementation to call. From my research so far, I have understood that one just have to add the Hibernate as a dependency and need not worry themselves with the patchwork. How does it work under the hood?

Comment: Are you using Spring, if so are you using Spring boot?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the persistence provider in peristence.xml to specify which implementation you are using.

This one uses Hibernate as the implementation.

```
<persistence-unit name="sampleEmf" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    ...

</persistence-unit>
```

This one uses EclipseLink as the implementation.

```
<persistence-unit name="sampleEmf" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    ...

</persistence-unit>
```